# I don't know why when i use the scanf function in C to get a number and print it out it is almost always 1

Tags: c

I am using gcc on arch linux the computer is an old dell inspiron.
In c I could write:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main
    {
    int x = scanf("%i",&x);
    printf("%i",x);
    }
```

i can compile this file and it will go through and it will give me 1.000000 for butting in any number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
double x;
x = scanf("%lf",&x);
printf("%lf",x);
}
```

i could stat the variable before scanf i can use %d.
i have looked around and found nothing really.
if you have any other questions please ask.
thank you.

edit i did not mean to have & with the printf x int &
edit added for information

Comment: You print out the return value of `scanf` - not the argument.

Comment: `scanf` requires a pointer to the variable where the input value is to be stored, but `printf` needs to be passed the value itself.  So the last line should be `printf("%i", x);` without `&`.  You should have got a compiler warning for that.

Comment: i made a mistake i did not mean to put the & with the printf.
thank you

Comment: Recall, you cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return*** to determine whether the input succeeded or failed. Failure to validate input invites *Undefined Behavior* in your code. (of course if you save the return, you use a separate variable, e.g. `int rtn = scanf("%i",&x); if (rtn == EOF) { /* handle EOF case */ } else if (rtn == 0) { /* handle matching failure */ } else if (rtn == 2) { /* good input */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x;
    scanf("%i", &x);
    printf("%i", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: better     `if(scanf("%i", &x) == 1)
    printf("%i", x);`

Answer (score 3):

You made 3 mistakes in 2 lines. You should read the documentation of the functions used.

1. `scanf` returns the number of the successfully scanned elements, not the scanned value. If you scan 1 object then if the `scanf` is successful, the return value will be always 1
2. `printf("%i", &x);` does not print the value of `x`, only the address (reference) of `x` using wrong format specifier which is UB.

Comment: I usually always warn about the consequence of failure to validate the input as well (just as you explain the consequence under your No. 2.). Nicely done.